# Connecting variables to another class

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, class

So I have a small project I am working on. Basically what I want to do is create another class, with the SQL connection as well as the results. However, it is telling me:

> The Name 'firstName' does not exist.

When I put it on the page that is created for the designer mode in visual studio, it goes away and works.

**info.cs**:

```
public void GetInfo(string accountNumber)
{
    string source = helper.CnnVal("WorkflowConfiguration");
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(source);
    con.Open();

    string sqlSelectQuery = $"Select TOP 1 * From [Workflow Creation].[dbo].[ssFields] Where Field16 =" + int.Parse(accountNumber);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlSelectQuery, con);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.Read())
    {
        firstName.Text = (dr["Field1"].ToString());
        lastName.Text = (dr["Field2"].ToString());
        dateOfbirth.Text = (dr["Field3"].ToString());
        socialSecurity.Text = (dr["Field4"].ToString());
    }

    con.Close();               
}
```

I would like to make a reference to the "designer" code page. So I can reference the results in the btn click below:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class dataBase : Form
    {
        List<Information> people = new List<Information>();
        private personalInfo personal = new personalInfo();

        public dataBase()
        {
            InitializeComponent();        
        }

        public void searchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataAccess db = new dataAccess();

            people = db.GetPeople(accountNumber.Text);
            ListBoxPeople.DataSource = people;
            ListBoxPeople.DisplayMember = "FullInfo";

            //Would like to references here from info.cs       
        }
```

Comment: You need to include the code where you declare `firstName`.

Comment: Also, please format your code - correct the indentations and remove all the extra white space

Comment: @rory.ap it would be in the second set of code. There are no declarations of firstName anywhere. I know that when I paste the code from the info.cs in the referenced spot in the second set of code, it works.

Comment: You should know that your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.  Use parameterized queries!

Comment: No, you need to include your code *here* in your question so we can see it.

Comment: Just make GetInfo() return a class that contains the information you want to get back. You can create a class that has the 4 data entries that you want. After the call to GetInfo() use the return value to assign the data to the controls.

Comment: @DennisKuypers I appreciate your feedback as well. With the combination of your help and Renato, I was able to get the desired results.

Comment: @maccettura Thank you for your input as well. I have since adjusted the statements and now have parameters. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be dealing with Windows Forms here, as your main class is a `Form`. To start things off, I would like to recommend against giving Forms names that are completely unrelated to them. I have the habit of naming the main forms of my applications `MainForm`, but you could also use, for example, `MyAppForm` (the name of your application plus the word Form).

Setting that aside, if you need to access a control on your form (such as a `TextBox`), I recommend that you do so **within the Form class itself**, unless you have an excellent reason to do so. You will not be able to reference things from outside the form class (as controls are `Private`), and even if you write a method to pull the controls from your Form, you won't be able to access them (they will be on a different thread), unless you implement an algorithm to get around that.

Therefore, I suggest that you move your `GetInfo` method to your form class. Notice that that class is a `partial` class, that means you can create a new class file with the same class name and it will extend your form class, better organizing things (this is what Designer code generation does, hence why you're not supposed to alter things on the Designer file).

**Edit**: Additionally, as suggested above, if the context of your form doesn't suit your method, you can also pass the data required by a control via an extra public acessible method. That extra method can be called by your Form event, for example.

**Note**: Be sure to define the class as `partial` on the other file as well, if you intend to do this.

Comment: So the better option, would just to include the code in the other class files then? Thanks for the input!

Comment: Yes. Generally when you need to access anything from a control on your form, you do it from inside, except in special cases.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance and guidance. I was able to get the same result, by removing a few lines and adding the additional options. I appreciate your help on this and have marked your answer as the best one, since you answered it. As for that I did give some kudos to Dennis as well, in the comments section.